# access infinispan .class in Clojure

Tags: clojure, infinispan, infinispan-9

I am trying to replicate a snippet of code from [the Infinispan documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#soft_index_file_store) in Clojure:

```
ConfigurationBuilder b = new ConfigurationBuilder();
b.persistence()
  .addStore(SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationBuilder.class)
  .indexLocation("/tmp/sifs/testCache/index");
  .dataLocation("/tmp/sifs/testCache/data")
```

Here is my attempt:

```
(import '[org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.configuration.SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationBuilder])
(import '[org.infinispan.configuration.cache ConfigurationBuilder])

(def b (ConfigurationBuilder.))

(.addStore (.persistence b)
           (class org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.configuration.SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationBuilder))

;; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.configuration.SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationBuilder
```

How do I get past this exception? This is the [SIFS source](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/persistence/soft-index/src/main/java/org/infinispan/persistence/sifs/configuration/SoftIndexFileStoreConfiguration.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case, you should have in your dependencies:

```
:dependencies  ... others here ...
               [org.infinispan/infinispan-core "9.0.1.Final"]
               [org.infinispan/infinispan-persistence-soft-index "9.0.1.Final"]
```

Also, you are using [import](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/import) incorrectly. You can either do:

```
(import full.package.name.ClassNameHere)
```

or

```
(import [full.package.name ClassNameOne ClassNameTwo])
```

For your case, you should be doing:

```
(import org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.configuration.SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationBuilder)
```

Note that unlike `require`, where a `nil` result means "everything's good," with `import` a `nil` return means "nothing was imported."